# Force Signed-In Google User to Login Again

Tags: google-oauth, google-signin

If a google user is already signed-in (i.e. logged in), is there a way to prompt or force the user to login again?  Specifically, I am looking for a URL that would prompt the user to type in their password again.

Answer (score 0):

Try [One-Tap Sign-Up and Auto Sign-In library](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/) Google announced last week.